# Can't login to fedora 29

Tags: fedora

I can't login to system. I wrote good login and password but i got back to logging panel. That happend when I install jdk 11.0.2 and set /etc/environment. This file include 2 lines:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/jdk-11.0.2
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/jdk-11.0.2/bin

I logged via ctrl+alt+F2, but when I logged, I saw a lot of errors and currently have got only basic commands, but can't install others. Can't use Sudo, su, rm, and so on commands.

What shlodu I do in that case?

https://m.imgur.com/gallery/n0Iy34V

Comment: This is not about programming. It should go to ServerFault or so

Comment: @Soleil Could you write simple example, cuz I'm titled by this situation?

Comment: Just go to ServerFault

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Ive never been in that situation. Could you give very, very simple list of tasks what should I do?

Comment: @Soleil 
I don't know how to do it. Ive never been in that situation. Could you give very, very simple list of tasks what should I do?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/ the same as with SO

Comment: @Soleil can't find article about my problem. I don't know did u understand me correctly. I added file with 2 lines to export Java..., then reboot system and when I wanted to log to pc, but I returned again to logging panel. When I pressed ctrl alt F2 and log as normal user, I couldn't use normal commands like sudo, su. Additionally couldn't log as root. I know password but it didn't work. So could you send to me directly link to post which explain problem or write to me in simply way?

Comment: I understood well. Just ask your question on Serverfault the same way you asked this question on Stackoverflow (SO). (tip: start in unique user configuration (you'll be root); (maybe: ^d twice, fast) then you'll be able to to whatever you need, in particuler, revert your changes in ~/.bashrc; in hard cases, make a liveCD/usbkey with rufus and edit your .bashrc files).

Comment: @Soleil THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It worked, i could delete wronge file when i ran liveCD. Again, thanks!!!